# Passing values from windows form to console application

Tags: c#, .net, soap, server-side

So I have a program that takes in the user credentials via Windows form, Now through the MessageBox I am currently displaying the user input, what I am trying to do is pass it into my console application so that if the user enters in the correct credentials it then continues in the console application, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you want to start console application while running windows form application and pass value from windows form application to console application?

Comment: The way the app works is the Console app launches first and then immediately the windows form pops up and takes in the information

Comment: If the windows form application start first then it is easy. But you want reverse. I have to think .

Comment: Why do you have two processes starting immediately?  Could you just have your windows application take credentials, then call a console application?  How "immediately" does the windows form get called?  By what?  someone click a batch script that opens two applications?  Your console opens a windows form?  etc..  Some more detail might be useful for the WHY of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need to add a while loop to look for a txt file in your console application. In your windows forms application, you can write a success or failure message into a txt file. (Add encryption for security) The moment you write down the information your console app should read it and continue from there.

```
Algorithm:
1.console application start
2. console app while loop until txt file detected
3. forms app show input screen
4. user enter credential
5. write success or failure into txt file
6. read txt file
7. continue based on credential result
8. Remove txt file
```

Since the form is also in the console app project (I assume it from your wordings) you can do the following

```
class Program
{
    public static object abc;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //do something here if required
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        if (frm.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //login success do what ever on success
            Console.WriteLine("Login success");
            Console.WriteLine(abc.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Login failure");
            Console.WriteLine(abc.ToString());
            //login failure
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

and the login button click event in your login form class

```
 private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(true)
        {
            Program.abc = "any success object here";
            //on successful login
        this.DialogResult= System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        }
        else
        {
            Program.abc = "any failure object here";
            this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Esen

Comment: On the console app it is already writing to a txt file, essentially in the program before i start everything including login was on the console, we are moving away from the console to a UI hence the Windows form, I have the user input store in the windows form section i just need to know how to pass it to the console application

Comment: Is the UI a seperate application or part of console app project?

Comment: its a part of the console app project

Comment: updated my answer with a simpler solution since the console app and the form is in same proj its easy to do this

Comment: If I were send it back to the console would it not be I create the object in the windows forms file and pass then in the console app?

Answer (score 0):

you could host a wcf service within your form app. then make the console app a client. creating a service oriented system is surprisingly easy with wcf. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16765/WCF-Windows-Communication-Foundation-Example) for a tutorial. you will learn a lot if you follow this approach

Comment: Do I really need to go through all those steps just to pass 5 values?

Comment: There's lots of ways to implement inter-process communication (e.g. Window messages, DDE, Pipes, TCP/IP), but none of them are much easier and would require developing your own custom (albeit simple) protocol.  WCF is a nice standard way to do it, though.

Comment: Could I not just pass it through an object?

Comment: you are trying to communicate accross app domain, so no. you could serialize an object and have your console app dig this out, but this is the same as the suggested text file approach really

Answer (score 0):

Use IPC (Inter process communication) with Named Pipes.Its easy to implement between two processes check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx

Comment: I will be quite easy to use a stream of characters rather than complicating it with objects.Just send True/False

Comment: Named pipes is probably overkill for something like this.

Comment: @techno sending true/false the console as part of a validation routine is too easy to bypass.

Comment: @JasonLarke Its quite easy,I don't think its too complicated there are inbuilt classes to do the job.Its not quite tough as C or C ++

Comment: I'm aware how easy to implement named pipes are with C#, I just don't see the need for them when this can easily be encapsulated within a single application. The two modes (GUI/Console) don't sound like they run concurrently so switching between the two is viable.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you'll probably have to use some native Windows API functions (Alloc/FreeConsole) and use a WinForms controller.

Semi-pseudocode:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool AllocConsole();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool FreeConsole();

//--- form code
if (Do_validation() && AllocConsole())
{
    this.Hide();
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    Enter_Console_Code();
    FreeConsole();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50); //FreeConsole sometimes doesn't finish closing straight away which means your form flickers to the front and then minimizes.
    this.ShowInTaskbar = true;        
    this.Show(); 
}
//---

private void Enter_Console_Code()
{ 
    string line = string.Empty;
    while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != "q")
        Console.WriteLine(line); //pointless code ftw!
}
```

Essentially what this code does is do your "GUI" validation step, and then if that's successful it attempts to allocate a console for the application. Once the console is allocated it enters "Console Mode" by completely hiding the GUI and displaying only the new console (closing the console closes the application by the way). Your "Console Mode" code is executed, then the console is closed and the GUI comes back.